# Java KeyListener events sleep for a while after resuming a game

Tags: java, awt, delay, keylistener, cardlayout

I use a KeyAdapter class for a character movement in a game. Here is a code of it:

```
    public class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter{
    private Game game;

    public Keyboard(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(0, true);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(1, true);
            System.out.println("KEY A PRESSED");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(2, true);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(3, true);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            game.pause();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(0, false);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(1, false);
            System.out.println("KEY A RELEASED");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(2, false);
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
            game.getPlayer().setAccelerate(3, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

On click of Escape it calls Game.pause():

```
public  void pause(){
    paused = true;
    pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cardContainer.getLayout();
    cl.show(cardContainer, "PAUSE_PANEL");

}
```

Then, if the user hits RESUME, it brings the game canvas back onto the screen, requests focus and resumes the game. But when i try to move my player or escape my game once more, KeyAdapter simply does not throw events. Is sleeps for  5-6 seconds, what makes a game unplayable. How can i fix this?

Comment: It's more likely that the component that the `KeyListener` is attached to has list focus

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  @MadProgrammer It's early in the morning here, so it took me a few moments to realize that by *"..attached to has **list** focus."* you meant *"..attached to has **lost** focus."*  OP - For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Who knows what I'm talking about, I'm a sleep deprived parent of a two year old